# C#: which Dlls are declared in the assembly manifest after the build

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

When I build a C# project that references many projects, I get in the output my dll.
I opened it with DotPeek to see its references and I get that some projects references are not there.

My question is : How the compiler decide to put the reference in the assembly ?

Comment: It needed them. If you reference an assembly but doesn't use any of the types in it, the reference may be removed at compile time. This can also happen if the only references you make are to constants, then the constants may be compiled into your assembly and no reference to the original is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few cases where a reference from project A to project B is removed when A is compiled:

1. You referenced B, but you did not in any way use anything from B
2. You referenced B, and only used constants in B

In the first case the reference turns out to be unnecessary, so it is not compiled into A.

In the second case the constant value is compiled into A instead of a reference to the constant in B, and thus the reference to B is now unnecessary, so it is not compiled into A.

If you create two projects, A and B, and reference B from A, and add these types:

```
namespace A
{
     public class AClass
     {
         public int Field = B.BClass.Constant;
     }
}

namespace B
{
     public class BClass
     {
         public const int Constant = 42;
     }
}
```

Then compile this and disassemble the A assembly you will see that there is no trace of the reference to B, and the compiled code for A.AClass looks like this:

```
namespace A
{
     public class AClass
     {
         public int Field = 42;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lasse V.Karslen  for this well explained answer. Isn't there another case where a reference to project B is removed. For example when using interface from another project ??